# Function containing a switch statement nested within a for loop. Takes integer and array. Trying to return number of iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

```js
/* 
Would take something like 
limesToCut(20, [large, small. large, medium, medium, small])
NEEDS TO STOP WHEN ENOUGH WEDGES ARE CUT AND RETURN 
NUMBER OF LIMES NEEDED
*/

export function limesToCut(wedgesNeeded, limes) {
  for (let i = 0; i < limes.length; i++) {
    switch (limes[i]) {
      case "small":
        wedgesNeeded = wedgesNeeded - 6;
        break;
      case "medium":
        wedgesNeeded = wedgesNeeded - 8;
        break;
      case "large":
        wedgesNeeded = wedgesNeeded - 10;
        break;
      default:
        wedgesNeeded = 0;
        break;
    }
  }

  return i;
}

}
```

Comment: So you need to add another conditional to your loop to exit out when wedgesNeeded is done.

Comment: `i` is out of scope where the `return i;` currently is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.